# Tkinter Entry validation for IP Address

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am taking IPv4 address as an input from the user, using Tkinter Entry and I would prefer using the validatecommand attribute of the widget which will only allow entries with the format XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, being X digits.

The problem can be solved with re module matching the entry with the expression ^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$ but I would like to do it beforehand.

I have tried using the ipaddress module as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ipaddress as ip
import re

def validate(value):
    if ip.ip_address(value):
        return True
    return False

window = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(window, text = "IP", font = 'Arial 10 bold').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'ew')
varip = tk.StringVar()
vcmd = window.register(validate)
ipadd = tk.Entry(window, textvariable = varip, width = 23, validate = 'key', validatecommand = (vcmd, '%P'))
ipadd.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
window.mainloop()
```

The thing is that only the first character introduced is checked to be an IPv4 address and all characters are permitted, not only digits and dots.

How could it be done?

Comment: So if I understand your query properly, are you having trouble validating correct IPv4 addresses?

Comment: The problem is that the Tkinter Entry widget allows me to introduce all characters from the keyboard and I would like to restrict it to only accept numbers and dots. The validation if the IPv4 address is correct or not could be done afterwards. Maybe I am not explaining myself well xd.

Comment: Are you asking how to restrict input to only digits and the period character? Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/7432?

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing issues validating your `Ipv4` you can add the following logic in your code. I have a similar `tkinter` program that requires *`Ipv4` validation*. This worked for me.

```
import re 

# Make a regular expression 
# for validating an Ip-address 
regex = '''^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.( 
            25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9][0-9]?)'''

# Define a function for 
# validate an Ip addess 
def check(Ip):  

    # pass the regular expression 
    # and the string in search() method 
    if(re.search(regex, Ip)):  
        print("Valid Ip address")  

    else:  
        print("Invalid Ip address")  


# Driver Code  
if __name__ == '__main__' :  

    # Enter the Ip address 
    Ip = "192.168.0.1"

    # calling run function  
    check(Ip) 

    Ip = "110.234.52.124"
    check(Ip) 

    Ip = "366.1.2.2"
    check(Ip)
```

Comment: Thats perfect to do once the Entry widget is filled, but I would like to restrict this Entry to only accept numbers and dots.

Comment: Either I dont understand your query or maybe you're not going through the regex. Because from the look of it it only accepts and validates numbers and dots only.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the problem as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

def validate(P, S):
    if S.isdigit():
        if 0 <= len(str(P)) <= 3:
            return True
    return False

window = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(window, text = "IP", font = 'Arial 10 bold').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'ew')
varip = tk.StringVar()
vcmd = window.register(validate)
ipadd = tk.Entry(window, textvariable = varip, width = 23, validate = 'key', validatecommand = (vcmd, '%P', '%S'))
ipadd.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to alter it if you don't want it to accept addresses like 999.999.999.999, but the regex that worked for me in a similar application is below. I wrote it to validate octet by octet. I'm still fairly new to this, so you'll have to excuse the PEP8 formatting issues.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re


def validate(P):
    test = re.compile('(^\d{0,3}$|^\d{1,3}\.\d{0,3}$|^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{0,3}$|^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{0,3}$)')
    if test.match(P):
        return True
    else:
        return False

window = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(window, text = "IP", font = 'Arial 10 bold').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'ew')
varip = tk.StringVar()
vcmd = window.register(validate)
ipadd = tk.Entry(window, textvariable = varip, width = 23, validate = 'key', validatecommand = (vcmd, '%P'))
ipadd.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
window.mainloop()
```